# Pattern matching for directory path

Tags: command-line

Can I use pattern matching with the `copy` or `move` command?

What I wanted to do is copy the file `a.txt` from `D:\1\2\datehere\a.txt` to another folder let us say `D:\new`.

The problem is that the source path folder is a date as a folder name which keeps changing. The files to be copied inside that stay `a.txt` and some other files. So how to copy `a.txt` to another folder.

Can I use something like pattern matching or do you have any other idea?

Comment: How do you know what `anyname` is? Suppose there's another subdirectory `someothername` - how would you know to copy `a.txt` from `anyname` rather that 'someothername`?

Comment: @PeterWright i have edited my question. The folder will be having name as the date(current date). So it keeps on changing.

Comment: OK - so next question - in which date format? Personally, I use YYYYMMDD but my display format is dd/mm/yy. When you execute `ECHO %date%` what do you see - and how would the `date` portion of your directoryname be structured? Would the directoryname have been created `today`? Would it simply be the `latest` directoryname - or the `latest directoryname containing the file` if it's possible for the directory to be created **after** your target but **not** contain the file?

Answer (score 0):

This searches in %userprofile% for the first folder with today's date as it's name and copies `a.txt` from there to the %temp% folder. Please assign your paths as needed.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "StartFolder=%userprofile%"
set "TargetFolder=%temp%"
set "FileMask=a.txt"

set "SourceFolder="
for /d /r "%StartFolder%" %%i in (*.*) do if not defined SourceFolder if "%%~nxi" equ "%date%" set "SourceFolder=%%~i"
if not defined SourceFolder echo Folder %date% not found&goto:eof
copy "%SourceFolder%\%FileMask%" "%TargetFolder%"
endlocal
```